# Edit some values in column sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, substr, listagg

I have a table:

| id | param | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 | value1 |
| 1 | p2 | value2 |
| 1 | p3 | value3 |
| 1 | p4 | value4 |
| 2 | p1 | value10 |
| 2 | p2 | value20 |
| 2 | p5 | value50 |
| 3 | p1 | value100 |
| 3 | p2 | value200 |
| 3 | p4 | value400 |
| 4 | p1 | value11 |
| 4 | p2 | value12 |
| 4 | p3 | value12 |

I want to have the next result:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value1, val,value3 |
| 2 | value10,val,value50 |
| 3 | value100,val |
| 4 | value11, val, value12 |

I know that I can union into one line using listagg, but I don't know how to take only 3 values's letters from p2 and write it in one column with other values.
My query:

```
 select listagg(p.value, ',') within group (order by p.id asc) from tab p 
where p.param like 'p1' or p.param like 'p3' or p.param like 'p4'
or p.value = (select SUBSTR(m.value, 0, 4) 
from tab m where m.param like 'p2' and m.id = p.id) 
group by p.id
```

I understand why my query is not working correct, but I don't understand how to do it

Comment: Please explain the rules for combining the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to take only 3 values's letters from p2 and write it in one column with other values.

You can use conditional logic in the `listagg()`:

```
select listagg(case when p.param = 'p2' then substr(p.value, 1, 3) else p.value end, ',') within group (order by p.id asc)
from tab p 
where p.param in ('p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4') 
group by p.id;
```

Comment: Hi @JuliaK , you may try to mark the answer as helping you.